# How do I end a repeating handler when it hits a certain condition?

Tags: java, android, audio, handler

I'm making an application that plays audio files off the device's storage, and I have a seek bar that checks the progress of the audio file (how long it has played) every second, and updates the seekbar accordingly.

The audio is played through a service that runs in the foreground, and also displays a notification that the audio is playing.

When the audio ends, I noticed the handler still goes in it's cycle, and I want to end the handler once the audio is done.

What I'm currently trying to do is to end the handler from inside the runnable that the handler runs, as I'm not sure how else I can end it.

Main Activity, where I handle OnClick from the ListView where you can select an audio file and also handles the seekbar update.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SeekBar musicProgBar;
    Handler progBarHandler = null;
    Runnable r = null;
    private MP3Service.MyBinder myService = null;
    TextView progressText = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        musicProgBar = findViewById(R.id.musicProgressBar);
        progressText = findViewById(R.id.progressText);
        final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.musicList);
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                null,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + "!= 0",
                null,
                null);

        progBarHandler = new Handler();
        final int progBarDelay = 1000; // delay for the handler, making it repeat itself only every 1000 miliseconds (1 second)

        lv.setAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                cursor,
                new String[] { MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA},
                new int[] { android.R.id.text1 }));

        Intent tempIntent = new Intent(this, MP3Service.class);
        startService(tempIntent);
        bindService(tempIntent, serviceConnection, 0);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> myAdapter,
                                    View myView,
                                    int myItemInt,
                                    long myLong) {
                Cursor c = (Cursor) lv.getItemAtPosition(myItemInt);
                String uri = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
                Log.d("g53mdp", uri);

                if (myService.fetchPlayerState() != MP3Player.MP3PlayerState.STOPPED)
                    myService.stopMusic();

                myService.loadMusic(uri);
                myService.playMusic();
                musicProgBar.setMax(myService.fetchDuration()); // set the max value of the seekbar to be the duration of the song
                r = new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        int tempInt = myService.fetchProgress();
                        Log.d("progress ticking", tempInt + " " + musicProgBar.getProgress());
                        musicProgBar.setProgress(tempInt); // sets the current progress of the seekbar to be the progress of the song
                        long minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(tempInt);
                        long seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(tempInt);
                        if (seconds >= 60)
                            seconds = seconds - 60;
                        String tempString = minutes + ":" + seconds;
                        progressText.setText(tempString);
                        progBarHandler.postDelayed(this, progBarDelay);
                        if (musicProgBar.getProgress() == myService.fetchDuration())
                            progBarHandler.removeCallbacks(this);
                    }
                };
                progBarHandler.post(r);
            }});
    }

    private ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection()
    {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service)
        {
            myService = (MP3Service.MyBinder) service;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name)
        {
            myService = null;
        }
    };

    public void playButClicked(View view)
    {
        myService.playMusic();
    }

    public void pauseButClicked(View view)
    {
        myService.pauseMusic();
    }

    public void stopButClicked(View view)
    {
        myService.stopMusic();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        unbindService(serviceConnection);
        progBarHandler.removeCallbacks(r);
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

What is strange is that in onDestroy(), I do use removeCallbacks to end the handler, and that works nicely. I know that it comes to the point where it calls for removeCallbacks in the Runnable r, confirmed through debugging and logging. Also tried implementing a method that is specifically for removing the handler and calling that, no luck. Also tried using return.

The part I'm struggling with is

```
r = new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        int tempInt = myService.fetchProgress();
                        Log.d("progress ticking", tempInt + " " + musicProgBar.getProgress());
                        musicProgBar.setProgress(tempInt); // sets the current progress of the seekbar to be the progress of the song
                        long minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(tempInt);
                        long seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(tempInt);
                        if (seconds >= 60)
                            seconds = seconds % 60;
                        String tempString = minutes + ":" + seconds;
                        progressText.setText(tempString);
                        progBarHandler.postDelayed(this, progBarDelay);
                        if (musicProgBar.getProgress() == myService.fetchDuration())
                            progBarHandler.removeCallbacks(this);
                    }
                };
                progBarHandler.post(r);
            }});
```

The service which handles the music player and handles playing the music

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;

public class MP3Service extends Service
{
    public static MP3Service instance = null; // implementing singleton by instantiating a reference to the instance
    private final String SERVICE_ID = "100"; // id for the service
    public static boolean isRunning = false; //
    NotificationManager notificationManager = null;
    int notificationID = 001;
    private final IBinder binder = new MyBinder();
    MP3Player mainPlayer;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return binder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRebind(Intent intent)
    {
        // TODO: implement Rebind for screen orientation change
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        instance = this;
        isRunning = true;
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mainPlayer = new MP3Player();
        super.onCreate();
        Handler handler = new Handler();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        isRunning = false;
        instance = null;
        notificationManager.cancel(notificationID);
    }

    public void createNotification() 
    {
        CharSequence name = "MP3 Notification";
        String description = "Displays a notification when a song is playing";
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(SERVICE_ID, name, importance);
        channel.setDescription(description);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        // when the user clicks the notification, this will bring them to the activity
        PendingIntent navToMainActivity = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

        // sets up the info and details for the notification
        final NotificationCompat.Builder mNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, SERVICE_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .setContentTitle("MP3 Player")
                .setContentText("Playing music")
                .setContentIntent(navToMainActivity)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);

        startForeground(notificationID, mNotification.build());
    }

    public void removeNotification()
    {
        stopForeground(false);
        notificationManager.cancelAll();
    }

    public class MyBinder extends Binder
    {
        public void loadMusic(String filePath)
        {
            mainPlayer.load(filePath);
        }

        public void playMusic()
        {
            mainPlayer.play();
            createNotification();
        }

        public void pauseMusic()
        {
            mainPlayer.pause();
            removeNotification();
        }

        public void stopMusic()
        {
            mainPlayer.stop();
            removeNotification();
        }

        public MP3Player.MP3PlayerState fetchPlayerState()
        {
            return mainPlayer.getState();
        }

        public int fetchDuration()
        {
            return mainPlayer.getDuration();
        }

        public int fetchProgress()
        {
            return mainPlayer.getProgress();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help, and I am happy to provide with more information if required

EDIT: changed the progBarHandler.postDelay() that is outside the runnable to a simple progBarHandler.post()

Answer (score 1):

I think the only reason you failed to stop the handler is constantly invoking `progBarHandler.postDelayed(this, progBarDelay);`,you need to check why it's still running.

Comment: Yeah I played around with it a bit more, and basically changed it so the code in the runnable would run only when conditions were met
`Runnable r = new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
if (musicProgBar.getProgress() == myService.fetchProgress() && myService.fetchProgress() != 0) Log.d("audio", "over");
else { ... progBarHandler.postDelayed(this, progBarDelay }`

This made it work, luckily

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it working by introducing a different kind of if statement to the runnable, like so

```
Runnable r = new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        if (musicProgBar.getProgress() == myService.fetchProgress() && myService.fetchProgress() != 0)
            Log.d("audio", "over");
        else {
            int tempInt = myService.fetchProgress();
            long minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(tempInt);
            long seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(tempInt);
            if (seconds >= 60)
                seconds = seconds % 60;
            String tempString = minutes + ":" + seconds;
            progressText.setText(tempString);
            musicProgBar.setProgress(tempInt); // sets the current progress of the seekbar to be the progress of the song
            progBarHandler.postDelayed(this, progBarDelay);
        }
    }
};
```

It seemed for some reason, using .fetchDuration() and .fetchProgress() will never equalize each other, so changing the if statement worked.